# practical usage of hadoop map reduce hive pig hbase

Tags: hadoop

Hello,
I am learning Hadoop and after reading the material found on the net (tutorials, map reduce concepts, Hive, Ping and so on) and developed some small application with those I would like to learn the real world usages of these technologies.

What are the everyday software we use that are based upon Hadoop stack?

Comment: Please ask real questions, don't copy paste! Edited!

Comment: Here's the best explanation of map reduce I've ever read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html.  And here are some real examples: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/PoweredBy/

Comment: Thanks Vincenzo..I went through the wiki real examples link.It shows most of the usage oh Hadoop technologies is for data analysis.e.g facebook uses it for analysing the logs.  What about storing data does that mean for applications storing petabytes of Big data, e.g Facebook all the posts and such data is stored on hbase tables and not sql?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the internet, there are good changes that you are indirectly impacted from Hadoop/MapReduce from Google Search to FaceBook to LinkedIn etc. Here are some interesting links to find how widespread Hadoop/MR usage is

[Mapreduce & Hadoop Algorithms in Academic Papers (4th update – May 2011)](http://atbrox.com/2011/05/16/mapreduce-hadoop-algorithms-in-academic-papers-4th-update-may-2011/)

[10 ways big data changes everything](http://gigaom.com/2012/03/11/10-ways-big-data-is-changing-everything/)

One thing to note is Hadoop/MR is not an efficient solution for every problem. Consider other distributed programming models like those based on [BSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel) also.

Happy Hadooping !!!

Comment: Thanks Parveen..I have done some sample programs on Hadoop Map Reduce, sample Hive queries and Pig scripts....what i want to know is how is it practically used say in Facebook.Are our posts stored in flat files and processed my MR? are the posts stored in HBase tables.If so is thre no need of relational database like SQL here?

Comment: praveen, were you able to answer monica's last question?

Comment: Since FB and other companies are closed, it's really difficult to know what they are doing unless you are working for one of those companies. The best is to follow some of the blogs like [1](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/), [2](https://dev.twitter.com/blog), [3](http://highscalability.com/) and know in bits and pieces what FB and other companies are doing.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://hadoopdeveloperguide.blogspot.in/) are some sample mapreduce examples which will be helpful for beginners..
1.Word Count
2.SQL Aggregation using Map reduce
3.SQL Aggregation on multiple fields using Map reduce

URL - http://hadoopdeveloperguide.blogspot.in/